# How to loop json results in Perl

Tags: perl, json, dbi

I am trying to output JSON from a perl script that accesses a mysql database.

How I can I loop through my query returns and turn that into JSON using the JSON module?

When I do this all I get is 1 return

```
while($query_handle->fetch()) {
    $jsonStructure->{event};
    $jsonStructure->{event}->{evid} = $evid;
    $jsonStructure->{event}->{component} = $component;
    $jsonStructure->{event}->{firstTime} = $firstTime;
    $jsonStructure->{event}->{lastTime} = $lastTime;
    $jsonStructure->{event}->{count} = $count;
    $jsonStructure->{event}->{summary} = $summary;
    $jsonStructure->{event}->{severity} = $severity;
}
```

Basically I have many events and don't know how to say event[0]...

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
push @{ $jsonStructure->{events} }, {
    evid => $evid,
    component => $component,
    ...,
};
```

although even that is probably overkill, because you can probably do something like:

```
while (my $row = $dbh->fetchrow_hashref) {
  push @{ $jsonStructure->{events} }, $row;
}
```

if all of the column names in the DB are the same as the field names you want in the JSON, and you want all columns, or:

```
my @keys = qw(evid component firstTime ...);

while (my $row = $dbh->fetchrow_hashref) {
  my %hash;
  @hash{@keys} = @$row{@keys};
  push @{ $jsonStructure->{events} }, \%hash;
}
```

if you only want some columns, or:

```
# DB colname => JSON field name
my %mapping = (
  event_id => 'evid',
  component => 'component',
  first_time => 'firstTime',
  ...,
);

while (my $row = $dbh->fetchrow_hashref) {
  my %hash;
  @hash{ values %mapping } = @$row{ keys %mapping };
  push @{ $jsonStructure->{events} }, \%hash;
}
```

for a completely arbitrary mapping. Power of Perl and all that. :)

Comment: Thanks hobbs, these are really great examples.